# What path should I put for img tag in printWriter for client to read it? (Connection via socket)

Tags: android

I am trying to make a web-page which would be served on local network, server being android device itself. (need to send this android data to matlab). Till now, am successfully being able to make plane text webpages with approach below. However now, I need to add an image to this webpage. When am using img tag like below, it can't find image(It does exist on storage and path is correct as well).

Complete Code for the same is [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/08/implement-simple-http-server-running-on.html). I used this guide to make my server

What should I do to put image on same context path for client to read it?

```
private class HttpResponseThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    HttpResponseThread(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader is = null;
        final PrintWriter os;
        String request;

        try {
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            request = is.readLine();
            os = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String response =
                    "<html><head></head>" +
                                    "<body>" +
                                    "<img src='" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/selfDrive/temp.jpg' alt='image' />" +
                                    "</body></html>";

                    os.print("HTTP/1.0 200" + "\r\n");
                    os.print("Content type: text/html" + "\r\n");
                    os.print("Content length: " + response.length() + "\r\n");
                    os.print("\r\n");
                    os.print(response + "\r\n");
                    os.flush();

                    socket.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On the client side, what URL is used to request the web page?

Comment: Local IP Address of Android : http://192.168.1.108:8080/
I can see the whole webpage, but there is no image.

Comment: `it cant find image`. With it you mean the browser? Or your server? If your browser you could try with changing `"<img src='" + Environment.getEx.....` to `"<img src='file://" + Environment.getEx....`.

Comment: It worked @greenapps :)

Comment: What browser are you using to access the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

A good alternate would be to create an ftp server in background with [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) and access image from there like `<img src='ftp://192.168.1.108:8080/pic.png'>`
This way accessing files on storage would be efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Web browser will parse the HTML of a web page and issue separate requests for each resource needed. In the case of an `<img>` tag, the browser will make a request using the `src` attribute. The URL in the source attribute can be any valid URL. Often it is a **relative** path based on the URL of the original HTML page. In such a case, the web browser is responsible for creating the actual URL by concatenating the HTML's URL and the relative path for the image.

When the server receives the request, it is responsible for parsing the URL and sending a response. In this case, you can specify what folder on the device corresponds to "http://192.168.1.108:8080", such as the external storage folder. Now you just load all resources relative to that chosen folder. For example if the incoming URL is  "http://192.168.1.108:8080/pic.png", the server parses out the file name "pic.png" and loads it from the chosen base folder.

As stated earlier, the HTML can contain a relative page, such as `<img src='pic.png'>` and the browser will concatenate it with the HTML page's URL to create the complete URL for the image resource.

Comment: My question is, how do I make http://192.168.1.108:8080 point to my external storage where it would refer to this image? As in, I want to point Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/images" as "http://192.168.1.108:8080/images"

Comment: @Rohit What are you using for a client? Are you using a standard browser or an app you built? Is the client also on the Android device?

Comment: I am using standard browser. It worked btw :) Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit Is it the standard browser on your android device? The accepted solution will not with if you use another device, such as a desktop computer, to access the web page on your phone.

Comment: I created an ftp server in background and was able to access image from there. That way it worked more easily.

Comment: @Rohit While your solution may "work" and give you the results you want, I don't believe it is the "correct" way to do it. At least not if you want to create a fully functioning HTTP server. The method I have outlined above will give you more flexibility along those lines.

Comment: Yes, I do agree to you @Code-Apprentice, it isn't correct solution to this question. Though it worked for me, but I would still would like to know how to make specify what folder on device corresponds to "192.168.1.108:8080". I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: @Rohit As I state in my  answer, you just decide which folder corresponds to http://192.168.1.108:8080. Then you parse the path of the URL and load all files relative to the folder you choose.

Answer (score 0):

`it cant find image`. With it you mean the browser? Or your server? If your browser you could try with changing `"<img src='" + Environment.getEx.....` to `"<img src='file://" + Environment.getEx.....`